# How do I clear highlighted foundation 5 top-bar sub menu item?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using a Foundation 5. Whenever I get to the 3rd level down in my top-bar dropdown menu one of the items is highlighted.

You can view my issue by navigating here on your mobile phone
http://changeyourenergy.theheavenlycode.com/mobile/default.htm

- Click Menu
- Click More
- Click Community

Now "News" is highlighted.  Huh?

I do not understand why this is since this does not happen on my desktop.

Devices this is happening on include:

- iPod Touch G4
- Samsung Galaxy 1 Android Phone
- Samsung Galaxy Note 2 Android Phone

Comment: I can't reproduce this on iPhone 5?

Comment: It is not working on the iPod Touch or Samsung Galaxy 1 Android Phone

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is highlighted on my iPhone, I think there is a problem with your device...